# Is there a way for python to take in a string with math operators and convert it to an expression?

Tags: python

I am trying to take a piece of user input: `5+5` or `5*5` but my code receives it as a string. I want to convert it to an expression from which an answer can be deduced. However, I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

For that there's a standard function called as `eval`.

Examples:

```
>>> eval("5*5")
25
>>> eval("5+5")
10
>>> eval("2+3*4-4")
10
```

It will take a string and then calculate the output as per the BODMAS Rule.

Comment: But if the user input is untrusted, [`eval` is dangerous](/a/9558001/4518341).

Comment: Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Oh is it ?? I wasn't aware. Let me read more. Thanks.

Comment: @Yash To avoid the danger? Yeah, the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string) has some solutions.

Comment: Yes, I think if the user enters a malicious piece of code then something bad could happen to my computer or application.

Comment: I think the linked duplicate should work. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Simply use "eval", but unsafe.

Comment: This isn't very informative. How do you use `eval`? Why is it unsafe?